# I made the form a component, it disappeared with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

### overview

Currently, the created new.vue and edit.vue have similar form parts, so I would like to make them common and componentized.
Therefore, I would like to create a new form.vue and display the page in the form of calling it.

However, when I made it into a component, the page disappeared.
(There is no such description in the log, and there is no error display in Console)

I think the data transfer isn't working, but I'm not sure where to fix it.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to fix it.

### Original code before componentization

###### New.vue

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <form>
      <section>
        <div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-3">
                  <label>タイトル</label>
                  <input v-model="latest_information.title" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-3">
                  <label>詳細</label>
                  <input v-model="latest_information.detail" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div class="btn-container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="button-square btn-send" type="button" @click="createLatestInformation">保存する</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      latest_information: {
        title: '',
        detail: '',
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createLatestInformation() {
      this.$loading.load(this.$auth.api.post('admin/latest_informations/', {
        latest_information: this.latest_information
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.$router.push({name: 'AdminLatestInformationIndex'})
      }))}
  },
}
</script>
```

### Code after componentization (not behaving well)

###### New.vue

```html
<template>
  <form :latest_information="latest_information" @click="createLatestInformation"></form>
</template>

<script>
import Form from './Form.vue';

export default {
  components:{
    Form
  },

  data() {
    return {
      latest_information: {
        title: '',
        detail: '',
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createLatestInformation() {
      this.$loading.load(this.$auth.api.post('admin/latest_informations/', {
        latest_information: this.latest_information
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.$router.push({name: 'AdminLatestInformationIndex'})
      }))}
  },
}
</script>
```

###### Form.vue

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <form>
      <section>
        <div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-3">
                  <label>タイトル</label>
                  <input v-model="latest_information.title" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-3">
                  <label>詳細</label>
                  <input v-model="latest_information.detail" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div class="btn-container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="button-square btn-send" type="button" @click="$emit('click')">保存する</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    latest_information: {
      title: '',
      detail: '',
    },
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

### Environment

rails 6
vue@2.6.10

Comment: Are there any messages being logged to the console?

Answer (score 0):

form was a reserved word.Changed to tform.

```
<template>
  <tform :latest_information="latest_information" @click="createLatestInformation"></form>
</template>

<script>
import Form from './Form.vue';

export default {
  components:{
    Tform: Form
  },
```